# how to convert Excel file to CSV and prevent UTF-8 encoding

Tags: python, excel, csv, utf-8

I have 5 Excel files that have to be compiled into one csv file that can be uploaded to our website for our affiliated stores database. Until now we've had someone manually cut and paste the rows of each file into one master csv file in Excel then they upload that file to the website.

I've been trying to use Python to consolidate the files so the user would just have to run the Python script that would do this for her. The problem is that the Excel files are encoded in Shift-JIS and when I use CSV writer in Python they get converted to UTF-8. The website we upload them to will only accept files in Shift-JIS, so I have to keep all of this data in Shift-JIS.

Since DOS automatically defaults to ascii encoding, I first have to run this:

```
import codecs, sys, xlrd, csv
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('shift_jis')
```

Here is a sample of the code for one of the Excel files, which has data on 2 separate worksheets:

```
with xlrd.open_workbook('Circle.xls') as wb:
   for sheet in wb.sheets():
     fn = 'store-'
     print "Converting files.."
     with open(fn + sheet.name + ".csv","wb") as f:
       c = csv.writer(f,dialect="excel")
       for r in range(sheet.nrows):
          c.writerow(sheet.row_values(r))
```

The conversion runs until it finds a UTF-8 character that doesn't exist in shift-JIS, then it errors out.

Is there a way to convert from Excel to a csv purely in shift-JIS?

(If my question has a flaw, please ask me to edit it before marking it down! I will edit it!)

Comment: Can you provide a sample Excel file? I have a feeling that it should be easily achievable with `pandas`.

Comment: Sorry to sound like an idiot, but what's the best way to share part of the file? I can cut and paste a few lines in a comment, but is there a way to attach a basic file?

Comment: Basically, is there a reason why the encoding of the terminal matters when the output goes from one file to another? It's not being printed to std.out, it's going from one file to another.